# Replacing link attributes to prevent spam

Tags: jquery, spam-prevention

I figured I could use this simple approach to create a low-level spam filter in jQuery -

```
<a class="filter" href="mailto:johndoe[at]nowhere[dot]com">johndoe[at]nowhere[dot]com</a>

$('.filter').each(function() {
  $(this).html().replace(('[dot]', '.'));
  $(this).html().replace(('[at]', '@'));
});
```

But nothing happens. The native replace function doesn't seem to cope with jQuery. I've also tried fetching the contents using val() and text(). Maybe this is altogether an incorrect method, if it is I'd appreciate some directions.

Comment: (offtopic) I use a nice trick of mine, I create 2 images: a dot (*.*) and a *@* in the same font I use in the page and just replace the characters I need. WHY? : spams bulletproofed the *[dot]* and the *[at]*. While `staffan<img src="imgz/point.png" />estberg<img src="imgz/monkeey.png" />web<img src="imgz/point.png" />com` looks much better **and still secured**. P.S. use **php**

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Interesting thoughts! I'll be sure to take that into consideration when creating something more secure later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following:

```
$('.filter').each(function() {
  var that = $(this);

  that.attr('href', that.attr('href').replace('[dot]', '.')
                                     .replace('[at]', '@'));

  that.html(that.html().replace('[dot]', '.').replace('[at]', '@'));
});
```

Comment: Neat! Thanks! Just wished I could understand why doing this approach is necessary. Need to learn more native JS...

Comment: strings are ***immutable***. the `replace` function returns a *new* string. as such, it needs to be used in the proper manner (capturing the result).

Answer (score 1):

Replace function does not modify original string. 
You need to use it like this:

```
$(this).html( $(this).html().replace('[dot]', '.') )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.filter').each(function() {
  var mail = $(this).html().replace('[dot]', '.').replace('[at]', '@');
  $(this).html(mail);
  $(this).attr('href',"mailto:"+mail);
});
```